# Ubuntu 14.04.01 - Unity Tweak Tool doesn't change theme and font settings

Tags: unity, themes, fonts, tweak

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.01 in a VirtualBox machine and Unity Tweak Tool works perfectly, everything.

However, after installing Ubuntu in a spare drive (not a virtual machine), Unity Tweak Tool doesn't change themes and font settings (hinting, antialiasing etc.). I haven't tested other settings, but at least it changes panel transparency settings.

Maybe it's something with NVIDIA drivers?

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem after my 14.10 hang up. Solved via:

1. Open `dconf-editor`
2. Go to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings`
3. Unset and then set again `active` checkbox.

Or

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings active false`
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings active true`