# Can't change window header style in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, themes, appearance

Today after reboot I got my appearance changed, everything: Icons, Fonts and etc. except cursors. Tweak tools I tried like *Ubuntu Tweak*, *Gnome Tweak Tool*, *Unity Tweak Tool* don't work, I couldn't change and apply the visual theme by using them.

I found this post and partially solved the issue. 
[Ubuntu 14.04.01 - Unity Tweak Tool doesn't change theme and font settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546947/ubuntu-14-04-01-unity-tweak-tool-doesnt-change-theme-and-font-settings)

Now I have weird window header and some fonts and elements. It is still got from another theme. In header it concerns control (min/max/close) buttons, gradient and shadow of top panel and Wi-Fi, sound, language switcher icons. Also after reboot all the changes I make disappear(.

Does anybody know how to make GUI completely apply the theme and make it persistent?

This is the theme I would like to work. (Unfortunately download link is broken).
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/lubuntu-box-theme-0-45-unity-support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this commands in terminal. Any of these command can solve your problem.

If something has been changed in compiz window manager (ccsm), this command will reset compiz.

> dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

If you have more than one window managers then you can try this command to make compiz your default window manager

> compiz --replace

If unity is the reason of problem, you can reset unity too with this command

> unity --reset

Hope this commands can solve your problem.

Comment: `compiz --replace` did the trick!

Comment: You are most welcome..  :-)